# Vim polyglot syntax highlighting not overriding default

Tags: python, vim, vim-plugin

I have made sure that `syntax on` was enabled, and I can see vim going from all-grey (no highlighting), to a colored version where there is some basic syntax highlighting going on. So default syntax highlighting works.

Afterwards, I have installed the `https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot` plugin to my vim editor. The contents of my `~/.vimrc` file read this way:

```
...

if has("syntax")
  syntax on
endif

...

call plug#begin('~/.vim/plugged')

Plug 'https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree.git'
Plug 'https://github.com/sheerun/vim-polyglot.git'

call plug#end()
...
```

After this, I didn't see any change. I still see this very basic syntax highlighting but nothing any different to what I had before. How to make polyglot override this very basic syntax highlighting?

Comment: You probably need `syntax on` after you load plugins

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Not sure that would be the problem... Since the syntax file will load at `FileType` time and will probably use the `'runtimepath'` at that time, so enabling syntax before loading the plugin *should* be fine... Right?

Comment: @PabloRibaltaPL Can you please be more specific? What file type are you experiencing this with? Can you give us a sample file that you think exhibits this issue? What do you not get highlighted that you expected to get highlighted? (In other words, describe what you're calling "basic"...)

Comment: @filbranden theoretically, yea. OP should explain what is expected to change (it’s possible the filetype doesnt have a better syntax)

Comment: I am trying to edit a python file. Without polyglot with `syntax on` if observe that there is a change compared to `syntax off`. Text is still white but class names and some reserved words change color. However, this palette stays on even after installing the polyglot plugin. I tried to do what @D.BenKnoble proposed, adding `syntax on` after loading the plugins but it still looks the same. The file's extension is `.py`. Might be also worth mentioning I am connecting to this machine via `ssh`